# Wrong texture unrwap when combining two textured objects with boolean union

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers, objects, faces

sorry for bothering, but I'm having a slight problem with using the union feature in the boolean modifier. I'm currently creating a wooden bridge that is made out of several textured planks. My goal was to create this bridge in a .blend file, and then append it into another file where all my final objects were combined. Whin I did this, I saw that I would have to append all the single planks from the file. I used the boolean union to combine the planks into one mesh, since this would make it easier to handle. But when the objects were in union, the unwrapped faces of one of the objects would deform and get randomly placed somewhere in the material of the other object. This would stretch out and show the wrong part of the texture at the wrong face.

tl;dr: Textures from different objects get messed up using boolean union, what other ways can I combine objects?

Does anyone know how to solve this? is there some other way to combine the items without ruining the texture? The mesh is also kinda complicated, and mapping the faces and creating the texture would be inconvenient AFTER combining all the objects.